# Why do we need Diffie Hellman?

Tags: cryptography, diffie-hellman

Diffie–Hellman offers secure key exchange **only if** sides are authenticated. for authentication, sides are using public/private key. so if side A knows the public key of the side B, then A can simply use that key to encrypt the message (or the new session key). why bother to use separate key exchange algorithm?

Comment: you may get better answers on crypto.stackexchange.com

Comment: or even on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange, particularly because your question starts with an incorrect premise (that both sides are "authenticated").

Comment: @msw Diffie-Hellman is important even if you can authenticate the communication partner (knowing his public key). Personally I consider SSL ciphersuites that don't use ephemeral diffie-hellman as flawed. And if you have no way at all to authenticate the other side(not even a shared symmetric secret), even diffie-hellman won't save you, since it can't prevent MitM.

Comment: Reposted on crypto.SE at: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3163/why-do-we-need-diffie-hellman

Answer (score 1):

Diffie Hellman is designed to exchange a shared key. So the question could be rephrased as: `Why would I want to use a shared key, when public/private key pairs offers encrpytion and ease of sharing public keys?`

The benefits of a shared key over public/private keys are:

- Shared keys have faster algorithms compared to public/private key algorithms and thus require less processing power.
- It is possible for attackers to impersonate when using public/private key encrption, if a certificate authority is compromised: See the [DigiNotar case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diginotar#Issuance_of_fraudulent_certificates).

Comment: ad1) we can use public/private key only as handshake to generate symmetric key for the session. it has the same cost as validation of other side's signature (performed in authenticated Diffie Hellman). ad2) if certificate authority is compromised then Diffie Hellman is not secure either (because sides aren't reliably authenticated). so still i see no difference between DH and asymmetric cryptography for session key exchange

Comment: You can use direct encryption to exchange a shared key without diffie-hellman, that's the way the plain RSA suites in SSL work. Your impersonation arguments makes no sense either. Impersonation is still possible if you use DH with a compromized certificate authority.